# MvvmCross: Calling Close on my viewmodel crashes Store app

Tags: exception, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I have an application that crashes when I call Close(this) in the viewmodel at level 2 (meaning can go back one page). One at level 3 (meaning can go back two pages) goes back fine.

I call this in the main app:

```
// Register the main view model
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(new MvxAppStart<StartScreenViewModel>());
```

In StartScreenViewModel I call

```
this.ShowViewModel<AddNewViewModel>();
```

And that viewmodel has a ICommand binding in the XAML that calls a function that calls:

```
this.Close(this);
```

When calling this Close(), I end up in the UnhandledException handler.
The exception message is:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsPage.LoadStateBundle(NavigationEventArgs e)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsPage.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OnNavigatedTo>b__0()
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsExtensionMethods.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OnViewCreate>b__0()
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(IMvxWindowsView storeView, Func`1 viewModelLoader)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(IMvxWindowsView storeView, MvxViewModelRequest viewModelRequest, Func`1 bundleLoader)
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

After some more digging and wondering about navigation, I figured it out.
I had overridden

```
OnNavigateFrom(...)
```

in the StartScreenViewModel, but had not called

```
base.OnNavigateFrom(...)
```

in the function body! Adding that called now allows navigation to work correctly. Noob!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that by default Windows Store apps dispose of pages that are not on the top of the navigation stack. You can override this behaviour.